# Как извлечь элементы списока из словаря?

Tags: python, парсер

Есть словарь в таком формате:

```
{'https': "https://['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']"}
```

Подскажите, как извлечь из него все элементы?

То есть, хочу получить именно эти элементы:

```
'123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [140]: d = {'https': "https://['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']"}

In [141]: import ast

In [142]: ast.literal_eval(d['https'].replace('https://',''))
Out[142]: ['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']
```

или [по рецепту @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582152/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/582331#comment775616_582331):

```
In [305]: ast.literal_eval(d['https'][len('https://'):])
Out[305]: ['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']
```

Из документации:

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)** Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or
>   container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: `strings`, `numbers`, `tuples`, `lists`,
>   `dicts`, `booleans`, and `None`.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

`ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)` - функция для **безопасного** вычисления (evaluate) строки, т.е. питоновская строка будет "распарсена" и выполнена. Работает только для строк содержащих следующие структуры: `strings`, `numbers`, `tuples`, `lists`, `dicts`, `booleans`, and `None`.

Comment: 1- Стоит на русском кратко упомянуть что ast.literal_eval() делает. 2- вместо `s.replace('https://','')` лучше `s[len('https://'):]` чтобы [удалить префикс строки](http://stackoverflow.com/q/599953/4279).

Comment: @jfs, спасибо! Дополнил ответ...

Comment: Смысл literal_eval распознать константы (Python literal) в строке, как они в коде пишутся, то есть: `{"abc", 123, (),[],{'a': True}, None}`. Но literal_eval не поймёт совершенно тот же объект, если он не в виде констант указан, к примеру: `set([])`. В целом лучше более переносимые форматы использовать такие как json вместо literal_eval

Answer (score 1):

```
# при условии что в качестве разделителя в list не " или ''' кавычки
dt = {'https': "https://['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']"}
res = dt['https'].split("'")[1::2]
# или
res = dt['https'][10:-2].split("', '")

>>> ['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']
```

Comment: элегантно получилось!

Comment: @MaxU первая же `\'` в строке  *тихо* сломает код. Ошибки должны быть громкими, чтобы данные не потерять.

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {'https': "https://['123.240.106.33:8998', '200.54.180.226:80', '186.103.201.74:8080']"}
for ip in eval(d['https'].split('https://')[1]):
    print(ip)

>>> '123.240.106.33:8998'
>>> '200.54.180.226:80'
>>> '186.103.201.74:8080'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Не случится ли беда, если в тот список попадет скриптовый код? eval ведь может его выполнить